# Is there an efficient way to search all questions and answers in Physics StackExchange?

Tags: support

Is there an efficient way to search all questions and answers in Physics StackExchange?  "Help" says to use the search box that's in the upper right hand corner of every page.  There's no search box there.  Is it because I'm using the Firefox browser?  Is there another way?

Comment: The search has moved to the center of the top bar. But oftentimes you'll be better off using Google.

Comment: This seems to be a detail in the help text which got missed in the [rollout of the new top bar](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/300829/280545); it's a network-wide issue.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's a network-wide issue, rather than just Physics. [Related question on mother meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/308717/280545).

Comment: I agree the question can be closed; it's been answered adequately.

Comment: With Google, you can specify use `search phrase site:site_url` for the 'better results' Emilio mentions